# Raise Command on User Control Button click in Main Window in MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I've created a user control and added it dynamically into the main window. In the user control is a button which is binded by relay command.

I want to raise that command from Main Window Form via MVVM pattern. How could it be possible?

Or is there any another to handle this scenario?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Since you using MVVM pattern consider "Messenging" or "Event aggregation". There are a lot of information about this. Just google it.

Comment: i am using vb.net as language....

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? We need some code to start with. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)